# Making a form halt other program activity like a messagebox (in VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, multithreading, messagebox

I want to create a custom form (in visual basic .NET) that will stop other process responsiveness until the form is acknowledged.  It would be a nice bonus if I can add a beep when trying to access the main program UI while this form is displayed as well (like how a messagebox does).

My initial idea was to create another thread for the messagebox-type form and have the main thread sleep until the messagebox-type form is responded too, however I think this would create a bug-like appearance on the main program as it simply wouldnt respond or update its UI (also worth noting, I have little experience working with multithreading, so this may be incorrect).

I really don't have much idea of how to proceed with this, any ideas and/or guidance are greatly appreciated.  thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this type of behavior is that for which there is ShowDialog()

this sample is on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx#Y0) page for ShowDialog()

```
Public Sub ShowMyDialogBox()
    Dim testDialog As New Form2()

    ' Show testDialog as a modal dialog and determine if DialogResult = OK.
    If testDialog.ShowDialog(Me) = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        ' Read the contents of testDialog's TextBox.
        txtResult.Text = testDialog.TextBox1.Text
    Else
        txtResult.Text = "Cancelled"
    End If
    testDialog.Dispose()
End Sub 'ShowMyDialogBox
```

When the code calls ShowDialog() the program continue on the testDialog and exits only when your user press OK, Cancel, Close or whatever method, which, in the called dialog, set the property DialogResult to any value different from DialogResult.None.

Comment: thank you! this was very helpful! now I would like my result to very depending on the button pressed in the form, however currently it always seems to return the value 2. Is there a way to change which buttons return what value from the showdialog() method?

Comment: oh I think i found it: would I use the dialog result property and set it to whatever value depending on the button pressed as part of the button.click event handler for each button?

Comment: only thing though: it seems it only likes certain results (the ones in the dialogresult enum.).  Is there any way I can make this except more/other values or is there another method that may allow this?

Comment: In that case you should create a public (integer) property in your form code. Set this property to the value required just before exiting from your form. This property will be visible outside the form until Dispose() (eg. Like testDialog.TextBox1.Text in the above example)